# $_GET not displaying data in textbox with space between word in url

Tags: php, url, textbox, get

I have a page `index.php` and i am fetching the values from url for a word.

```
<a href="index.php?skills=software engineer">Software Job</a>
```

In code below, it displaying the full value from `$_GET`, but its not showing in textbox

and url is

```
http://localhost/mysite/index.php?skills=software%20engineer


<?php

    if (isset($_GET['skills']) and !empty($_GET['skills'])) {
        $is_skill = 1;  // true and has value
        $skill_data = $_GET['skills'];
        echo "The searched skills : " . $skill_data; // Here its displaying full values
    } else {
        $is_skill = 0;  // false and has no value
    }

?>



<input type="text" name="textbo1" <?php if ($is_skill == 1) { echo "value=" . $skill_data; } ?> />
```

Now, in textbox, its not display the full value ie `software engineer` where as in
php code output is

```
The searched skills : software engineer
```

and value in textbox : `software`

Dont know what is the issue, need help on this why it doesnot accept

Comment: replace echo "value" . $skill_data; with echo '"value='.$skill_data.'"';

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Attribute values with spaces in them must be quoted.

```
value=software engineer
```

… is parsed as "A value attribute with the value 'software' and 'An engineer attribute'

You are also vulnerable to an XSS attack and your URL is invalid.

Corrected code:

```
<a href="index.php?skills=software%20engineer">Software Job</a>
```

and

```
<input type="text" name="textbo1" <?php 
    if ($is_skill == 1) { 
        echo 'value="' . htmlspecialchars($skill_data) . '"'; 
    } 
?> />
```

Note you need to make *all* instances of external data safe for HTML with `htmlspecialchars`, not just the one I fixed in this example.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" name="textbo1" value="<?php if ($is_skill == 1) { echo $skill_data; } ?>" />
```

Your html-markup in not correct. You have to enclose your value in quotes. If `$is_skill` is 0, there will be no value in the textfield.

Answer (score 0):

Your attribute value needs to be in quotes. Use addslashes to escape and double quotes in the string itself.

Try this:

```
<?php if ($is_skill == 1) { echo 'value="' . addslashes($skill_data) . '"'; } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need quote

```
<input type="text" name="textbo1" <?php if ($is_skill == 1) { echo "value=\"" . $skill_data . "\""; } ?> />
```